# I'm trying to use TensorFlow with my own csv data but seeing a harmless "Enqueue operation canceled" warning

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm not sure what's wrong. I checked this [link](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/133267887103/tensorflow-placeholder-queue-errors) and tried to fix the error but it still is there. I'm trying to read in csv data and then predict the outcome of a column. No extra libraries, just barebones tensorflow to get a better understanding. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit:

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["keystrokes-strsep.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[''], [''], [''], [''], ['']]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
# print tf.shape(col1)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(114729):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Error:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x7fe343d3fa40 Compute status: Cancelled: Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueMany[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer, input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:286] Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually an informational message normal during operation rather than an error. This message indicates that there were records waiting to get pushed onto the queue when you did `request_stop`. In particular, you would see if if your cvs file had more than 1200+`queue capacity` records.

Comment: oh alright thanks! I think I will try using numpy instead then since this method can't read a lot of csv entries

Comment: actually this method is more scalable than numpy because it can use multiple threads for reading data

Comment: done by Google = for sure more scalable :P except I need it to work xD
what do you suggest me do for resolving the queue capacity issue? I am just beginning to learn about TensorFlow and its library

Comment: there's no queue capacity issue, what you are seeing is a harmless informational message, there's no error

Comment: do you know why the phrasing is 'enqueue process is canceled'? I printed each iteration of the for loop and everything printed. I don't know what got canceled.

Comment: this reflects some internal details that are happening underneath (you can find more about them in threading and queues howto: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks for the information. Do you think you can give us a complete code example of leading a CSV file using tf? It would be very useful for many users.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, using Numpy is simpler to read values from csv. See this simple code:

```
xy = np.loadtxt('train.txt', unpack=True, dtype='float32')
x_data = xy[0:-1]
y_data = xy[-1];
```

Then, you can feed x_data, and y_data for your operations.

See more at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html
.